# Jenkins: how to run shell script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins could not run shell script. I've installed Jenkins on my kubernetes cluster. 
Here is the part of build console output:

```
    Start building Frontend and Backend Docker images
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Building Bmf Frontend Image
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
Buildinging Bmf Backend Images
[Pipeline] sh
+ chmod +x build.sh
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] sh
+ chmod +x build.sh
[Pipeline] sh
+ ./build.sh --build_bmf_frontend
build.sh - Script for building the  Web Application, Docker image and Helm chart
Usage: ./build.sh <options>
--build_bmf_frontend    : [optional] Build Bmf Frontend image
--build_bmf_backend     : [optional] Build Bmf Backend image
--push_bmf_frontend     : [optional] Push Bmf Frontend image
--push_bmf_backend      : [optional] Push Bmf Backend image
--delete_frontend       : [optional] Delete Bmf Frontend image
--delete_backend        : [optional] Delete Bmf Backend image
--deploy_stage          : [optional] Deploy to Stage Server
--deploy_production     : [optional] Deploy to Production Server
--registry reg          : [optional] A custom docker registry
--docker_usr user       : [optional] Docker registry username
--docker_psw pass       : [optional] Docker registry password
--tag tag               : [optional] A custom app version
-h | --help             : Show this usage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
```

The job is executed on kubernetes worker provisioned from template Kubernetes Pod Template.

Here is my Jenkinsfile command:

```
stage('Build BMF Frontend') {
          steps {
            container('jnlp') {
            echo 'Building Bmf Frontend Image'
            sh "chmod +x build.sh"
            sh "./build.sh --build_bmf_frontend"
          }
          }
        }
```

Below is a screenshot of my Jenkins workspace;

[image: This is my workspace]

Comment: could you share your  `build.sh` script?

Comment: The jenkins build console output *is showing 15 lines of output from the shell script*, so the script is obviously executed. Voting to close as the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline is executed correctly.

The output returned suggests that the issue is from your script.

Even though Jenkins executed successfully, you do not get it to work as projected owing to a problem in your code.

You may want to check your `build.sh` script, probably the section where it parses input options.

Answer (score 0):

When using the snippet generator, all sh commands are generated with single quotes. Perhaps you should use that instead?

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator

Answer (score 0):

I am executing it with **sh** which has a less extensive syntax ;)